# Konjunktiv-II fill in the blank exercise: würden vs wären

Tags: subjunctive

My attempt:

> Ohne ihr hervorragendes Training **würde** das sicherlich anders verlaufen

Correct answer:

> Ohne ihr hervorragendes Training **wäre** das sicherlich anders verlaufen

Why is mine wrong? I thought "würden" can be used with anything to make K-2

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your last statement because it sounds like "würden" is a verb; it's an inflection of "werden".

Comment: Yours is not "wrong", it just means something different: In the correct answer, the competition (or what ever it is, what "verlaufen" refers to), happened in the past, while in your attempt, it will happen in the future, and you express that the outcome of the competition depends on her training.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the exercise, and the intended meaning. *Verlaufen* can both be an infinitive (as in *soll* or *wird verlaufen*) and a past participle (as in *ist verlaufen*). Looking at the other verbs in the exercise might help – are they infinitives *(ablaufen)* or participles *(abgelaufen)*?

As far as *wäre verlaufen* versus *würde verlaufen* is concerned, the difference is that between past and non-past; both have the value of a subjunctive and express [irrealis mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood). The difference is observed in continuations such as the following.

> Ohne das Training **wäre** das anders **verlaufen** (abgelaufen). Aber glücklicherweise **ist** es so **verlaufen**.
>
> Ohne das Training **würde** es anders **verlaufen** (ablaufen). Aber glücklicherweise **verläuft** es so.

Note that the first example is simply the perfect of *verlaufen* with the auxiliary in the past subjunctive *(wäre)* and the present indicative *(ist)*, respectively.

Since both *wäre verlaufen* and *würde verlaufen* are grammatical, yet *wäre verlaufen* is indicated as the correct answer, I assume the exercise requires one to use the "subjunctive of the past" (perfect with the auxiliary in the past subjunctive; *Konjunktiv Präteritumperfekt* in the [IDS terminology](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/685)).

Comment: Worth noting explicitly, since it’s only implied in your answer, that **both** options produce grammatically valid sentences, so devoid of context, the option chosen by the asker _isn’t_ wrong. If the exercise is simply asking to choose between _werden_ and _sein_ in Konjunktiv-II with no further specification, both should be considered correct answers.